# Absorbing variables in fixed effects model

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I’ve tabulated some statistics for 13 different industries across 11 years from the Current Population Survey and I’m now exploring some simple models that produce very different results. For now, I’m just experimenting with different models that might explain differences in median wage rates based on the median age and the percent of the workforce that consists of racial minorities in an industry. I'm using a package in the Julia programming language that is modeled after some of Stata's panel regression functions (which I'm not familiar with).

I'm hoping someone can help me understand what the `absorb` function does (Stata also has this). Here's an example of what my panel data look like:

```
Row │ hryear4  prmjind1  prcnt_minority  median_wage  wage_10  median_age
     │ Int64    Int64     Float64         Float64      Float64  Float64   
─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │    2010         1        0.549525      10.0      8.0           36.0
   2 │    2010         2        0.285844      18.0     11.0242        40.0
   3 │    2010         3        0.389158      16.0     10.0           37.0
   4 │    2010         4        0.372013      14.5      9.0           43.0
   5 │    2010         5        0.33117       10.0      7.5           34.0
```

`hryear4` is the year and `prmjind1` is the industry code. My baseline model looks like this:

```
Continuous Response Model
Number of observations: 143
Null Loglikelihood: -366.63
Loglikelihood: -325.47
R-squared: 0.4378
LR Test: 82.32 ∼ χ²(2) ⟹  Pr > χ² = 0.0000
Formula: median_wage ~ 1 + median_age + prcnt_minority
Variance Covariance Estimator: OIM
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                     PE         SE      t-value  Pr > |t|      2.50%     97.50%
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
(Intercept)       6.0373    2.52437     2.3916     0.0181    1.04648  11.0281
median_age        0.380779  0.0465285   8.18378    <1e-12    0.28879   0.472769
prcnt_minority  -13.9391    3.37746    -4.12709    <1e-04  -20.6165   -7.26168
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Now, when I `absorb` the time variable, year in this case, I get the following:

```
Continuous Response Model
Number of observations: 143
Null Loglikelihood: -366.63
Loglikelihood: -275.76
R-squared: 0.7206
Wald: 130.57 ∼ F(2, 130) ⟹ Pr > F = 0.0000
Formula: median_wage ~ 1 + median_age + prcnt_minority + absorb(hryear4)
Variance Covariance Estimator: OIM
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                     PE        SE      t-value  Pr > |t|       2.50%     97.50%
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
(Intercept)      11.5913    1.9173     6.04561    <1e-07    7.7981     15.3844
median_age        0.348849  0.034185  10.2047     <1e-17    0.281218    0.41648
prcnt_minority  -24.6077    2.65854   -9.25608    <1e-15  -29.8673    -19.3481
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

which looks to me like it's a much better model. However, I really don't understand what's happening here. My baseline model is just normal OLS and I understand that completely so how do I interpret the differences between the baseline and the version that `absorb`s the time variable?

Does absorbing the time variable mean that we are treating time as a fixed effect? If so, what does that mean in plain language?